# How can I forward a subdomain to another domain but follow all pages

Tags: .htaccess, subdomain, forward

I need to setup a sub domain to point to a certain part of another website, for example

Swindon.ukontheweb.co.uk to point to - http://ukontheweb.co.uk/location/england/wiltshire/swindon/

But I need the sub domain to follow all links not just a forwarding, so when you click a link on the Page it will show like this - Swindon.UKontheWeb.co.uk/ all pages of site

Baisically need the Subdomain to forward to new sites page but Subdomain to remain in Browser and follow links so Swindon.ukontheweb.co.uk/ anypage of new site.

I am new to this so I hope someone can help

Answer (score 0):

You must have already created A record for subdomain in domain panel. 
In your hosting panel, you simply have to point **document root** for your subdomain to the directry you mentioned. 
It will not be forwarding but be working like you require.